# Objective-c: presentViewController from UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Im trying to use presentViewController inside a UIView.

http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/6334/appt.png

When I click he "+" button at the top/right, I want to replacer the tableview at the right (in the grey part of the image) by a UIViewController.

```
- (void)add:(id)sender
{
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testview"];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Of course by doing this, the whole screen is replaced..
I want something like this:

```
[contentView addSubview:controller];
```

or

```
[contentView presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

where contentView is an UIView containing the tableview

I found this [addChildViewController and presentViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136391/addchildviewcontroller-and-presentviewcontroller) but I don't think that can help me out

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Use ContainerView in storyboard solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the controller's `view` as a subview of your `contentView`.  Be sure to keep a strong reference to the controller when you do that though.

Another approach would be to make the new view owned by the presenting controller instead of a second controller and simply hide/show views as needed.

Comment: By doing this way, I don't have the "animation" effect :/ Moreover, the controller.view is a way bigger than it mustt be ? Weird, I've put exactly the same width/heigh in interface builder. Anyway, thank you a lot :)

Comment: If you want complete control, then you may need to create a "container view controller" to be the detail view and have `controller` as its child.  In the end, there's a view hierarchy and a controller hierarchy and they don't substitute for each other well.

Comment: Try a Google search on `"container view controller" site:apple.com`.  There are some good references.

Answer (score 1):

edit your statement:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

try this and then let me know if it worked!

Comment: It does not work :/ by doing this the controller takes the whole screen, i just want it to take the same position that the tableview

Comment: why dont you do something like this:
[contentview addSubvie:controller];

and then presentViewController:contentview animated:YES completion:NULL];

Comment: because contentview is not a ViewController :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you right. From your picture I believe you are programming for an iPad, and you want to cover the whole view partly by another view. If so, you could use a `UIPopoverController`, which does exactly this.

Comment: I just want to replace the tableview at the right by a new view controller (at the same position with the same dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

A PopoverController seems to be what you need. Here is some boilerplate code:

```
UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                     initWithContentViewController:navigation];

self.aPopoverController = aPopover;


[self.aPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:nil inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

aPopoverController is a property of the class.

```
@property UIPopoverController* aPopoverController;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand clearly. This would help you out

```
SomeViewController *viewController=[[SomeViewController alloc]init];

[viewController setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];

[self.view addsubview:viewController.view];
```

Sorry if Iam wrong...