# presentViewController in containerview

Tags: objective-c, ios7, viewcontroller, multipeer-connectivity

First, this question isn't a duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786875/objective-c-presentviewcontroller-from-uiview), because the solution doesn't fits my problem.

I'd like to show a `MCBrowserViewController` by `presentViewController` inside a `container`. Because I don't want, that the presented controller goes over the whole screen.

My ViewController with the container inside, looks like this:
[image]

I have to use the `presentViewController`, because my `MCBrowserViewController` needs this method to trigger important parts.

My problem is, that I don't know how to present it, because the container is, obviously a view and I have no clue, how to do it.

How can I use the present-method to show the viewcontroller inside the container?

Comment: You can, theoretically use some of the iOS 7 techniques to perform `presentViewController` in a manner where the presented view controller doesn't take up the whole screen (see [Custom View Controller Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?include=218#218)), but before we go down that rabbit hole, perhaps you can describe a bit of what that view controller is doing that requires `presentViewController`.

Comment: The MCBrowserViewController starts searching for other devices if it is presented by the presentViewController. The browse-controller is a framework-controller.

Comment: Can you explain more why it needs to be presented, rather than just added as a child view controller in the container? What about the presentation causes things to be triggered?

Comment: I would have thought that if you do the typical containment processes (`addChildViewController`, `addSubview`, `didMoveToParentViewController`, etc.) that it would have worked fine. The only reason for requiring `presentViewController` would be if it (a) is was poorly designed such that it required the full screen; or (b) it was using `dismissViewController` to dismiss itself. But I don't know that controller, so I cannot comment on that. But that video I reference above shows how to present view controllers that don't take up the whole screen, but I wouldn't advise it for most circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

I tried adding an MCBrowserViewController as a child view controller, and that worked fine. It started searching as soon as it was added. In this example, the IBOutlet contView, is to a regular UIView (not a container view), whose purpose is only to set the frame of the MCBrowserViewController in IB.

```
    -(IBAction)showController:(id)sender {
        MCPeerID *peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:@"MyPeer"];
        MCSession *session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:peerID];
        MCNearbyServiceBrowser *browser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:peerID serviceType:@"Service1"];
        MCBrowserViewController *mcb = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithBrowser:browser session:session];
        [self addChildViewController:mcb];
        [mcb didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        mcb.view.frame = self.contView.bounds;
        [self.contView addSubview:mcb.view];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The frame of the presented view controller is determined by the presentation context, which is normally provided by the root view controller (i.e. the full screen). However, any presenting controller in the presentation hierarchy can provide the context simply by setting its `definesPresentationContext` property to return true. Then its frame will be used to determine the frame of the presented view. (see Presentation Contexts Provide the Area Covered by the Presented View Controller in  Apple’s [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW5))